# Objective-C and creating new object on the heap

Tags: objective-c, heap-memory

I'm new to objective-C programming, and I'm experiencing some trouble when trying to create an object in a method. The purpose of the program is to make a way to represent a directed graph, that I'll later use for testing graph theory.

The problem.

```
//From GraphObject.m
-(void) addNode
{
    GraphNode *newNode = [[GraphNode alloc] initWithId:count];
    [graphNodes addObject:newNode];
    NSLog(@"Node %i added", count);
    count++;
}
```

This excerpt is from my GraphObject class and is where the program breaks. It breaks on the first line in the block. 
This method is meant to create a GraphNode object and put it in a NSMutableArray (named graphNodes) of the GraphObject class. The count variable simply keeps track of how many nodes have been added. 
Being used to C++ I have a hard time seeing why it won't just put the object on the heap, and let me use it. Btw. The exact same line functions correctly if I place it in my main, which throws me a bit off.

If anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Here's the initWithId method. I'm starting to suspect the cause might be here. Does it have to return a pointer to self?

```
-(id) initWithId:(int)n
{
    nodeId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:n];
    neighbourNodes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    return self;
}
```

The memory leak you're mentioning (yAak), I'm assuming it's about the creation of GraphNode arrays within this method. But won't that be solved when I delete the array that I'm putting them in? If I delete them in the same method, nothing will be put in the array, as far as I see. Also, I'm sorry for not posting any error messages as I'm new to xcode, but I simply can't see any. The build is successful and it just simply says that the program stopped at a certain line in the code.

EDIT2 (And solution): Well, here's a weird surprise. I removed/cut the code and ran the program once, and then pasted the exact same code back in, and it's working fine now. That's one stable IDE right there. Thanks again for the replies, I'm sure I'll be back here soon though.

Comment: Post the error you're getting when it breaks.  All I see wrong here is a potential memory leak, which wouldn't cause the break.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of -[GraphNode initWithId:]? Also, please post the error message you're seeing. There's nothing about the code you've posted that sticks out as being incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Your initializer:

```
-(id) initWithId:(int)n
{
    nodeId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:n];
    neighbourNodes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    return self;
}
```

should look like this:

```
- (id)initWithId:(int)n
{
    self = [super init]; /* << or whatever the designated initializer of the superclass is */
    if (nil != self) {
        nodeId = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:n];
        neighbourNodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];
    }
    return self;
}
```

As far as the heap, well every NSObject instance you create is reference counted and on the heap. Clang won't even allow you to make objc objects on the stack (GCC would).

When you think your heap is messed up or your objects or their members are released prematurely, remember that there are a bunch of memory/ref count diagnostics tools: Zombies is one, GuardMalloc and scribbling are others. Of course, Leaks is also a good check.

Comment: Thank you, will fix this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Leaks, NSZombies, etc. are all useful tools. But when esp. when you're new to the language (and sometimes even when you're not), the best way to fix memory management issues like this is:

1) read this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

2) look at your code again.

3) reread this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

[... etc]

In this case, since you you didn't take ownership of the NSNumber object, it was deallocated before the next cycle of the application's run-loop.

This didn't happen in main because you were outside the application's runloop and didn't have an autorelease pool (you probably got a console message saying that the object leaked because there was no autorelease pool). If you're not sure what that is, read the section on autorelease pools in the linked doc.